# Eccentricity of Hyperbola

Tags: geometry

The normal to the hyperbola $\frac{x^2}{a^2} - \frac{y^2}{b^2}=1$ drawn at an extremity of its Latus Rectum is parallel to its asymptote. Show that the eccentricity is equal to the square root of $\frac{1+√5}{2
}$

I calculated the eccentricity but it contains $a,b$terms

Comment: Please show your calculation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Asymptotes have equations $y=\pm \dfrac{b}{a}\,x$

Foci have coordinates $(\pm \sqrt{a^2+b^2},\;0)$

A point $P$ at an extremity of the latus rectum has abscissa $x_P=\sqrt{a^2+b^2}$ and ordinate which can be found plugging $x_P$ in the equation of the hyperbola

$\dfrac{a^2+ b^2}{a^2}-\dfrac{y^2}{b^2}=1$

$y_P=\pm \dfrac{b^2}{a}$

The tangent to the hyperbola in a point $P(x_P,\;y_P)$ can be found with the formula

$\dfrac{x_P x}{a^2}-\dfrac{y_P y}{b^2}=1$

In explicit form $y=\dfrac{b^2  x_P}{a^2 y_P}\,x-\dfrac{b^2}{y_P}$

the slope is $m=\dfrac{b^2  x_P}{a^2 y_P}$

The normal has the slope $m'=-\dfrac{a^2 y_P}{b^2 x_P}$

If it is parallel to the asymptote then must be $m'=-\dfrac{b}{a}$

So we have the relation $\dfrac{a^2 y_P}{b^2 x_P}=\dfrac{b}{a}$

Now let's substitute the actual values of the coordinates of $P$

$\dfrac{a^2\dfrac{b^2}{a}}{b^2 \sqrt{a^2+b^2}}=\dfrac{b}{a}$

simplifying

$\dfrac{a}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}}=\dfrac{b}{a}\quad(*)$

Eccentricity for hyperbola is $e=\sqrt{\dfrac{b^2}{a^2}+1}$

so we substitute $b/a=t\to b=at$ in the equation $(*)$ the eccentricity can be written as $e=\sqrt{t^2+1}$. We get

$\dfrac{a^2}{a^2 t^2+a^2}=t^2 \to \dfrac{1}{t^2+1}=t^2$

and $t=\sqrt{\dfrac{1}{2} \left(\sqrt{5}-1\right)}$

so $e=\sqrt{\dfrac{1}{2} \left(\sqrt{5}-1\right)+1}$

$e = \sqrt{\dfrac{\sqrt{5}+1}{2}}$

Hope this helps

Comment: Please modify $\dfrac{a^2+2 b}{a^2}-\dfrac{y^2}{b^2}=1$ with $\dfrac{a^2+b^2}{a^2}-\dfrac{y^2}{b^2}=1$ rest is okay